Read data from Kafka running on docker using a spark application running on kubernetes
I have a kafka broker set on docker using docker-compose. My goal is to create a spark application which will run on a kubernetes cluster and read data from this kafka broker. I am using the below docker-compose file to create the kafka broker.
version: '2'
services:

  ed-zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    container_name: ed-zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  ed-kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: ed-kafka
    depends_on:
      - ed-zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    volumes:
      - streaming_data:/data:rw
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: ed-zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://ed-kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://127.0.0.1:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "raw:1:1"

volumes:
  streaming_data:

However, when i try to give ed-kafka:29092 as the kafka brokers in spark application it gives me error saying 'Unresolved Host-ed-kafka:29092'.
How can i create a set up where my kubenetes spark app is able to connect to my external docker container.

Don't mix container environments!  Can you run the Kafka broker in Kubernetes too, maybe as a StatefulSet?  If not, then the call into the Docker environment will need to go via the host running the container – you can't directly call between a Docker environment and a Kubernetes environment – and it will look like you're talking to the host machine, including things like the Kafka broker advertisement system.

How can i connect to the docker container via the host ?. It would be great if you could share an example. The reason why i am running it a docker container is that i want to treat it as a external server. If this does not work may be i will go with the option of creating the kafka broker on kubernetes.

Kubernetes and Docker Compose do not share any network connection, so DNS names will not work.
You could modify KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS, PLAINTEXT_HOST address with your external IP / hostname rather than localhost, then that should be resolvable from Kubernetes pods (on port 9092)
Otherwise, you should use something like Strimzi Operator to deploy Kafka in Kubernetes then connect to it, using Kubernetes networking features
